# Magento 2. File was not uploaded. (DomainException(code: 0) - Mageplaza customer attributes - Single file attachement

Tags: php, file, debugging, magento

first of all, many thanks for existing ! It is the first time i am seeking help on stackoverflow because i am totally stuck with this problem.

I am using the MagePlaza module 'customer attributes' and i added some single file attachements to the signup form.

When the form is submitted via POST, i get this error :

[2020-09-17 12:20:19] main.CRITICAL: File was not uploaded. 0/tmp/phptsoveS {"exception":"[object] (DomainException(code: 0): File was not uploaded. 0/tmp/phptsoveS at /home/u498309604/domains/green-riders.fr/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php:192)"} []

If i'm not mistaken 0 is code for success, yet the error is thrown.
I checked my php.ini and everything is fine on this side.
Also, i did 777 permissions on pub/ directory.

Mageplaza support says it has nothing to do with their module code, it's the call to php upload that fails.

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.
Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Is the file below the `upload_max_filesize`? You can check by adding a file with `phpinfo()` what setting it is seeing.

Comment: Hello dear. Thanks for answering. The file is 233KB and the upload_max_filesize == 128MB. I believe it is not related to the file size as when i upload the file from admin back office (customer section), everything goes smoothly.

Comment: It seems like something related to the MagePlaza customer attributes module. I opened a ticket and i am waiting for them to investigate this.

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone has this issue, updating Mageplaza Core module solve the issue